# Error al hacer uso de la función Dateadd

Tags: sql-server, date

Estoy en la creación de una función Table-valued en SQL Server pero estoy presentando un error al momento de hacer uso de la función `Dateadd`, este me genera como error el siguiente mensaje:

```
The definition for column 'Dateadd' must include a data type
```

La sintaxis de la función que estoy construyendo es la siguiente:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTravelsCustomers]
(   
    @TypeOp int=0,
    @Customer varchar(50)
)
RETURNS @Response table (Estatus varchar(50), ClaveCustomer varchar(50), Dateadd(HOUR, HorasArribo, FechaHoraSalida) ETA, Lote varchar(50), Address varchar(150), OC varchar(50)) 
AS
begin
   Insert into @Response (Estatus, ClaveCustomer, Dateadd(HOUR, HorasArribo, FechaHoraSalida) ETA, Lote, Address, OC)
    SELECT  Estatus,
            ClaveCustomer
            Dateadd(HOUR, HorasArribo, FechaHoraSalida) ETA,
            Lote,
            Address,
            OC
    FROM    TravelVw V
    WHERE   Estatus = 'PROGRESS'
    and     TypeOp = Case when @TypeOp = 0 then TypeOp
                                When @TypeOp = 1 then 'FLASH'
                                When @TypeOp = 2 then 'SMALL'
                            End
    and     isnull(@Customer, '0') in ('0', ClaveCustomer)  
    and     TypeOp != 'SALE'


    Select  V.*,  I2.Coment, I2.MODIFIEDBY, I2.CreatedDateTime
    From    @Response   V
    left join (Select   I.Travel, 
                        isnull(I.Coment, '-') Coment,
                        I.ModifiedBy,
                        DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETUTCDATE(),GETDATE()), I.CreatedDateTime) CreatedDateTime
             From   dbo.Travel I 
             Where  I.CREATEDDATETIME = (   Select MAX(CREATEDDATETIME) 
                                            From dbo. I3
                                            Where I.Travel = I3.Travel
                                        )
             ) I2 on V.Travel = I2.Travel
)
return
end
GO
```

He intentado agregando el tipo de dato `HOUR, DATE, DATETIME,` pero no consigo éxito.

Agradezco quien pueda darme una orientación en saber que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: pero por qué estás agregando la función cuando estás declarando la tabla?, ahí simplemente pon el nombre de la columna y el tipo de dato

Comment: Puedes aportarme un ejemplo como respuesta en base a tu comentario para validarlo

Comment: es que no es una respuesta. Tú estás declarando la estructura de la tabla, ahí tienes varias columnas con su nombre y tipo de dato....haz lo mismo para la columna que que quieres calcular el tiempo

Comment: @Lamak Te refieres a que solo coloque en el `Returns` que se encuentra al comienzo de la función el nombre de la columna y el tipo de dato de la siguiente manera  `RETURNS @Response table (Estatus varchar(50), ClaveCustomer varchar(50), ETA datetime, Lote varchar(50), Address varchar(150), OC varchar(50))`

Comment: sí, exactamente

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios problemas en tu consulta. El principal es que estás usando una función en vez de una columna. Otro problema, es que estás haciendo una consulta que no inserta nada a la tabla que estás regresando, por lo que eso generará un error a la hora de compilar. Por último, te falta una coma en tu consulta para insertar.

Hay problemas adicionales de rendimiento, como el hecho de que tus condiciones no podrán utilizar índices o el hecho de usar funciones tipo tabla que no sean "en línea".

Dejo un ejemplo de como podría funcionar.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTravelsCustomers]
(   
    @TypeOp int=0,
    @Customer varchar(50)
)
RETURNS @Response table (
    Estatus varchar(50), 
    ClaveCustomer varchar(50), 
    ETA datetime, 
    Lote varchar(50), 
    Address varchar(150), 
    OC varchar(50)) 
AS
begin
   Insert into @Response (Estatus, ClaveCustomer, ETA, Lote, Address, OC)
    SELECT  Estatus,
            ClaveCustomer,
            Dateadd(HOUR, HorasArribo, FechaHoraSalida) ETA,
            Lote,
            Address,
            OC
    FROM    TravelVw V
    WHERE   Estatus = 'PROGRESS'
    and     TypeOp = Case when @TypeOp = 0 then TypeOp
                                When @TypeOp = 1 then 'FLASH'
                                When @TypeOp = 2 then 'SMALL'
                            End
    and     isnull(@Customer, '0') in ('0', ClaveCustomer)  
    and     TypeOp != 'SALE'

    /*
    Esto no corresponde ya que la función está hecha para regresar solo la tabla @Response
    */
    --Select  V.*,  I2.Coment, I2.MODIFIEDBY, I2.CreatedDateTime
    --From    @Response   V
    --left join (Select   I.Travel, 
    --                    isnull(I.Coment, '-') Coment,
    --                    I.ModifiedBy,
    --                    DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETUTCDATE(),GETDATE()), I.CreatedDateTime) CreatedDateTime
    --         From   dbo.Travel I 
    --         Where  I.CREATEDDATETIME = (   Select MAX(CREATEDDATETIME) 
    --                                        From dbo. I3
    --                                        Where I.Travel = I3.Travel
    --                                    )
    --         ) I2 on V.Travel = I2.Travel

return
end
GO
```

Comment: No me queda del todo claro el porque no ya utilizar el ultimo fragmento de mi función allí se encuentran dos columnas las cuales requiero para la visualización completa, estas columnas son `MODIFIEDBY` y `CreatedDateTime`

Comment: Alguna novedad respecto a mi ultima duda? antes de darle la respectiva validación a la respuesta

Comment: No se puede utilizar el último fragmento porque genera un error. Todo lo tienes que insertar en la tabla que estás regresando. Esa tabla no tiene esas columnas.